# Using max result as a value for a predicate in SQL

Tags: syntax

Say I want to find all the employees that earn more than all of the employees of Google, is it possible to use the result from max as if it was a single value and not a table like so?

```
select person-name
from Works
where salary > ( select max(salary)
        from Works
        where company-name == "Google" )
```

(Works has the columns person-name, salary and company-name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Your query has several syntax errors however.

1. a dash in an identifier is invalid. I used an underscore instead in the below example. If you did create the columns that way, you will need to quote them, e.g. `"person-name"`
2. the equality operator in SQL is `=`, not `==`
3. String constants need to be put in single quotes (`'`) not double quotes

It is possible to use the result of the max subquery as a single values because it is a single value. To be accurate it is a subquery that because of the `max()` returns a single column and a single row.

```
select person_name
from Works
where salary > (select max(salary)
                from Works
                where company_name = 'Google');
```

You could use an alternative way with `> ALL` instead of `>`, with a subquery that doesn't have an aggregate function and returns many values (many rows but still a single column):

```
select person_name
from Works
where salary > ALL (select salary
                    from Works
                    where company_name = 'Google'
                      and salary is not null );
```

Note the `salary is not null` condition in this second query. Nulls must be taken out of the comparison because each of them would evaluate the `>` operation to *unknown* rather than *true* or *false*, and as a result the whole `> ALL` condition result would be *unknown* and you would get no rows in the output.

Answer (score 1):

This is SQL Server syntax (you haven't said what version of SQL you are on) but you could declare it as a variable;

```
DECLARE @GoogleSalary int; SET @GoogleSalary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Works WHERE [company-name] = 'Google')

SELECT
    [person-name]
FROM Works
WHERE salary > @GoogleSalary
```

Comment: It's old theoretical SQL, not some live version. I'm not sure what is the official name of it other than just "SQL".